# PKIX path building failed sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException

Tags: java, exception, validation

All of sudden today I am facing this issue when I am trying to call an api.
This issue was not existing till last night and now it's killing my application

> > SearchRadiusAction - url: https://connection.api.isp.mynetwork.be/getAccount2.cgi 
> >     sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Last night it went to production and now it's not working where it worked fine earlier.

I would like to know how to fix this if possible without code change.

Comment: You are using https. Have you checked whether the certificate used by the getAccount2.cgi service for SSL can be traced back to a root certificate trusted by your program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution.

I just downloaded the certificate files from the opposite server and installed them in my application server. :)

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem as well, after importing the certificates of the mail server and the CA, the problem still persisted.

As a general rule, enable SSL debugging by adding the option

```
-Djavax.net.debug=ssl
```

This shows the actual key stores and certificates loaded.

In my particular case, the reason was quite surprising: Avast anti-virus was doing man-in-the-middle between my application server (WildFly) and the remote TLS connection :O

Here are the logs:

```
15:49:57,112 INFO  [stdout] (default task-56) chain [0] = [
15:49:57,112 INFO  [stdout] (default task-56) [
15:49:57,113 INFO  [stdout] (default task-56)   Version: V3
15:49:57,113 INFO  [stdout] (default task-56)   Subject: CN=mail.irisel.com, O=Irisel Consulting SL, L=Tres Cantos, ST=Madrid, C=ES
15:49:57,114 INFO  [stdout] (default task-56)   Signature Algorithm: SHA1withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.5
15:49:57,114 INFO  [stdout] (default task-56) 
15:49:57,115 INFO  [stdout] (default task-56)   Key:  Sun RSA public key, 1024 bits
15:49:57,116 INFO  [stdout] (default task-56)   modulus: 138674107939081515882972971404534700919819495458616389928335346488718131998599706435849369388241463110190321699739219608756226058473158126297068838696077495178250043211055383692800846587509903813185937024462913474510326460163355093830472808797012578670617819870186505308700964920784184093349004872582841740643
15:49:57,116 INFO  [stdout] (default task-56)   public exponent: 65537
15:49:57,117 INFO  [stdout] (default task-56)   Validity: [From: Thu Oct 01 11:52:40 CEST 2015,
15:49:57,117 INFO  [stdout] (default task-56)                To: Tue Oct 09 11:52:40 CEST 2040]
15:49:57,118 INFO  [stdout] (default task-56)   Issuer: CN=Avast Web/Mail Shield Root, O=Avast Web/Mail Shield, OU=generated by Avast Antivirus for SSL/TLS scanning
15:49:57,118 INFO  [stdout] (default task-56)   SerialNumber: [    456c195d c1429a4b a1b6da53 c03eb04b]
```

Often I think that antivirus create more problems than they solve...